# How to freely modify color of bookest package?

Tags: color, books

I would like to use the [`bookest` class](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookest) because it suits very nicely my needs, however, I would like to modify the color in the headings and titles etc.

In the [`bookest` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/bookest/bookestdoc-en.pdf) it mentions the class offers 8 generic color variants: 
`blue`, `green`, `red`, `guitgreen`, `sssupcolor1`, `sssupcolor2`, `sssupcolor3` and `enscblue`, but also allows for definition of `colorA` and `colorB`.

However, I somehow seem to not understand the use of 
`\colorA{R G B}`, when I define it with `\colorA{220 0 130}`, it is just not taken into account.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It actually doesn't provide `colorA` and `colorB`. It provides macros `\colorA` and `\colorB` that actives the respective colours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `\setcolorA{<R>,<G>,<B>}` (note the comma-separated list `,`) where 0 <= `<R>`, `<G>`, `<B>` <= 1, after which you can use `\colorA`. The latter effectively calls `\color[rgb]{<R>,<G>,<B>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[green]{bookest}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}

\setcolorA{0.8235,0.2745,0.1451}% ~ 210,70,37
This is some {\colorA text using colour \verb|\colorA|}.

\noindent    
\SETcolorB{\color[RGB]{210,70,37}}%
This is some {\colorB text using colour \verb|\colorB|}.
\end{document}
```

Note how `\colorA` uses the `rgb` colour model by default, and therefore requires the values to range between 0 and 1. If you want to use values that range between 0 and 255, then you need to use the `RGB` colour model, for which you can use `\SETcolorX`.

---

If you want to use a different document theme colour than those provided by default, just redefine colours `A` and `B`. They will be used instead. For example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{bookest}
\SETcolorA{\color[RGB]{145,144,245}}% Plum-ish
\SETcolorB{\color[RGB]{160,159,250}}% lighter Plum-ish

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{A section}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

---

For changing specific colours of the chapter header, you'll have to patch `\@makechapterhead`. By default it sets the chapter text (header and title) using `\colorA`, and the rules using `\colorB`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[green]{bookest}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\SETcolorB{\color[RGB]{145,144,245}}% Plum-ish colour
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\colorA\Huge}{\colorB\Huge}{}{}
\patchcmd{\sectionfont}{\colorA}{\colorB}{}{}
%\patchcmd{\subsectionfont}{\colorA}{\colorB}{}{}
%\patchcmd{\subsubsectionfont}{\colorA}{\colorB}{}{}
%\patchcmd{\paragraphfont}{\colorA}{\colorB}{}{}
%\patchcmd{\subparagraphfont}{\colorA}{\colorB}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{A section}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The above patch changes `\colorA` to `\colorB` for the chapter *title*, as well as for the other sectional headers.

Comment: Thank you! I actually would like to have the green "CHAPTER 1", the "A chapter" and the 2 lines not in green but in plum. Your example shows how to color text, but not the headings (like does here the document class option [green]. Unfortunatley I cannot replace green by plum, but is it possible to change it so as to have the same behaviour ?

Comment: @Markus: I've added something to show how you can change the theme to a different colour. Just update what `\colorA` and `\colorB` shows.

Comment: That is great! Thank you! Knowing what to ask for is already the half way to solution ;-) I asked for "modify the color in the headings and titles etc." and gave the exemples of the generic colors which do exactly that, but just not in the color plum. -- There is still a headnote in green left (CHAPTER 1; or if I replace chapter by \title => "0.1 A section"). Is there a solution to avoid this too? I like a lot the way you displayed the patchcmd, very clear and useful!

Comment: @Markus: "headnote"? Are you referring to "Chapter 1"?

Comment: @ Werner: Now there we are!! Great stuff, your last edit made it perfect! Thank you so much!